# Explicitly shared photo facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

It's a way possible to send a photo to facebook with explicitly_shared false and not appear in timeline of user?

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
```

Or maybe... I am sending in the open graph a storie to facebook and the image doesn't go to album, it's possible?

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("fb:app_id", "app_id")
            .putString("og:type", "object_type")
            .putString("og:title", title())
            .putString("og:description", message)
            .putString("og:url", urlShare)
            .putString("og:image", imageUrl)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("action_type")
            .putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true)
            .putObject("object", object)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("object")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareApi.share(content, this);
```

The image in ".putString("og:image", imageUrl)" goes to storie and timeline but I want the same image in the album photos too. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem doing two requests to facebook, one with the storie and other with the photo to album, if anyone knows another way to do just one request would be good.

Comment: Can you please share your code. I have stuck in the same from 1 week. Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how you toggle user generated: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/f24dc751971af8d295add875b5e23221aded470f/facebook/src/com/facebook/share/model/SharePhoto.java#L151

Looks like it already defaults to false. If you want to use the graph api directly, here's the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#Creating

If you do an OG share, the photo will go into the apps album, I don't know a way to disable that.